# SQL returning empty JSON brackets when no value found instead of empty "value"

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a sql query which which will check a table called **USER_PROFILE_ENTRY** for **STRING_VAL** under a specific where clause as given below and set it for **extension_locale**

```
    Select extension_locale = (select STRING_VAL from USER_PROFILE_ENTRY
            where PROFILE_KEY = 'Culture' and ottr.USER_ID = USER_PROFILE_ENTRY.USER_ID)
            from USER_DATA ottr where USER_TYPE = 'U'
            FOR JSON PATH
```

the **ottr.USER_ID** in the where clause is from a table called **USER_DATA** so when you run below query and if there is no value which satifies this condition -> **ottr.USER_ID = USER_PROFILE_ENTRY.USER_ID** then nothing will be returned

```
select STRING_VAL from USER_PROFILE_ENTRY
            where PROFILE_KEY = 'Culture' and ottr.USER_ID = USER_PROFILE_ENTRY.USER_ID
```

But what I want is, if there is no value for above where condition, it should print
extension_timezone = ""
instead of not printing anything at all.

Below is output of above query :

```
[
  {},
  {
    "extension_locale": "en-US"
  },
  {},
  {
    "extension_locale": "en-US"
  },
  {
    "extension_locale": "en-GB"
  },
  {},
  {},
  {
    "extension_locale": "en-GB"
  },
  {
    "extension_locale": "en-GB"
  },
  {
    "extension_locale": "en-GB"
  }
]
```

So if you see the output, there are many **{}** (empty blocks) it means there was no satisfying where clause hence and empty output but what I want is like this :

```
[
  {
    "extension_locale": ""
  },
  {
    "extension_locale": "en-US"
  },
  {
    "extension_locale": "en-US"
  },
  {
    "extension_locale": "en-GB"
  },
  {
    "extension_locale": ""
   },
  {
    "extension_locale": ""
  },
  {
    "extension_locale": "en-GB"
  },
  {
    "extension_locale": "en-GB"
  },
  {
    "extension_locale": "en-GB"
  }
]
```

Comment: for json path in 2008? Are you a wizard?

Comment: Can you post test data? Also, note that JSON support was introduced in SQL Server 2016, so the `sql-server-2008` tag seems to be wrong. What is your actual SQL Server version?

Comment: What type of test data do you want? I have 2 tables, one is USER_DATA and other is USER_PROFILE_ENTRY, both tables have one common column, which is USER_ID which I am using in where clause

Comment: Not like this. Read the guidelines in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question with proper sample data - and also, fix the wrong tag. Then I might be able to help you.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have 2 tables, one is USER_DATA and other is USER_PROFILE_ENTRY, both tables have one common column, which is USER_ID which I am using in where clause. I hope I am able to make you understand

Comment: @ZoharPeled also, about the output, if there is no matching USER_ID in USER_PROFILE_ENTRY, compared to USER_ID in USER_DATA, then that JSON BLOB will come empty, since where clause will return nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

- Use `INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES` option in the `FOR JSON AUTO`. In this case the result is an `"extension_locale": null` key\value pair in the generated output
- Use `COALESCE()` to return the default value when the returned value from the inner `SELECT` statement is `NULL`. Then the result is an `"extension_locale": ""` key\value pair in the final JSON.

It's difficult without test data, but the following example, based on your code, is a possible option:

```
SELECT extension_locale = COALESCE(
   (
   SELECT STRING_VAL 
   FROM USER_PROFILE_ENTRY 
   WHERE PROFILE_KEY = 'Culture' AND ottr.USER_ID = USER_PROFILE_ENTRY.USER_ID
   ),
   ''
)
FROM USER_DATA ottr 
WHERE USER_TYPE = 'U'
FOR JSON PATH
```

Comment: It worked I was trying to user CASE for this but was not able to come to a solution. Marking this as answer